# How to set value in child from parent?

Tags: angular

I have this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5XbuxoGG6NqomayLP4Ae?p=preview

I have this:

```
> @Component({   selector: 'my-app',   template: `
>     <layout [child]="childModal">
>      <div class="body">
>       <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
>     <div class="modal-body">
>     {{5+7}} {{item}}
>     Hi heloo </div>
>     </common-modal> 
>      </div>
>     </layout>
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>
>    
> 
>   `, })

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal :CommonModalComponent;
  item:number=150;
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

}
```

How in layout commponent i can set item from App component. Any suggestion? My question is how to set child variable from parent if i dont have in child only parent component and some other components.

```
<parent>
<some-other-component></some-other-component>
</parent>
```

I dont have selector for child.
How can i change in layout component value of item that is in AppComponent?

EDIT:
This is what im trying to do:
https://plnkr.co/edit/BVS2AlQNZ7kO5wbsTBaA?p=preview

But emit is not working for some reason.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you please explain?

Comment: how can i change in layout component value of item that is in AppComponent..

Comment: You are already doing that with 'item' - you set it to be 150.  You can just assign a different value to 'item', and it will be reflected in the dialog.

Comment: i want on click in layout component on some button to change value in appcomponent of item. Right now i have fixed value and i want to add button in layout component and when i click on that button to set item = 200. Never mind what value its just i want to change it from layout

Comment: You mean something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/VsgJTBGfeFUPiHb5tqcK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an input variable to the item inside the layout component and an output variable to emit an event to your app component handle it and change the value of your item variable.

**AppComponent**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <layout [child]="childModal" [item]="item" (itemChange)="onItemChange($event)">
     <div class="body">
      <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{5+7}} {{item}}
          Hi heloo
        </div>
      </common-modal> 
     </div>
    </layout>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>


  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal :CommonModalComponent;
  item:number=150;
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
  onItemChange(item) {
    this.item = item;
  }
}
```

**Layout**:

```
import {Component,Input, Output, ViewChild, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'layout',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-body">
    <button (click)="show()">CLICKKK</button>
        <ng-content select="div.body"></ng-content>
      </div>
  `,
})
export class Layout {
   @Input() title?:string;
   @Input() child;
   @Input() item;
   @Output() itemChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter;
  constructor() {
  }
  show() {
   this.item = 200;
   this.child.show();
   this.itemChange.emit(this.item);
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I think you haven't understood my answer... so take a look at this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/mFcoiXqFedN1RO7tsETX?p=preview

I coded it and added some comments to explain.